# How to automate server backups in Windows Home Server?

Tags: backup, automation, incremental-backup, windows-home-server

I've set up a server backup for my Windows Home Server in the WHS console, but don't see a way to automate the backup to have it run on a scheduled basis in a similar manner to client backups. How can I accomplish this?

I'd like to use the existing server backup system if possible, as opposed to putting together some custom backup setup.

Comment: Note that WHS v2 includes automated backup based on Windows Server Backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arathorn-

As Brent mentioned, there is not built-in way to automate the server backups, but following the steps in the following article, you can make it happen (in a nutshell it uses AutoHotKey to record a macro that simulates clicking on the Server backup button).

http://www.mediasmartserver.net/wiki/index.php?title=Automating_the_Windows_Home_Server_Shared_Folder_Backup

-Sean

Answer (score 0):

When the server is backed up - All it does is backup up the profile drives and shares. There is no real OS backup as far as i can tell. Personally i use [Keepvault](http://www.keepvault.com/) to back these folders up. Fortunately i was able to get the service while it was still 99 dollars for unlimited GB

Comment: I don't need the OS backed up -- WHS restore functionality covers that. I'm just looking to find a way to automate the existing server backups. Keepvault is not really an option as I'd like to work with the existing server backup system in WHS.

Answer (score 0):

After you install the [Windows Home Server Power Pack](http://blogs.technet.com/homeserver/archive/2009/03/23/windows-home-server-announcing-power-pack-2.aspx) and plug in an external drive, you can back up the server manually - but you can't schedule a backup.  You have to click the link to run it on demand.  You're right, that blows, but it's the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

Use ntbackup.exe instead to schedule a backup of whatever directories you want, including your desktop/workstation backup directories ;)